# Routes path helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I created a new route, like this:

```
  resources :animals do
    member do
      get ':id/resumed_rep_life', :action => 'resumed_rep_life'
    end
  end
  match '/animals/:id/resumed_rep_life' => "animals#resumed_rep_life"
```

How can I made a link for it?

I tried `resumed_rep_life_animal_path(animal)` but it does not work (method not found). 
Are my routing correct?

Comment: Note: you can always check what `rake routes` return if you're not sure what the generated helpers will look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
match '/animals/:id/resumed_rep_life' => "animals#resumed_rep_life"
```

to this:

```
match '/animals/:id/resumed_rep_life' => "animals#resumed_rep_life", :as => 'resumed_rep_life_animal'
```